# How do I prevent elements losing their position on window resize

Tags: css, sass

I'm building a responsive navigation, using only html and scss at this point; but I've encountered a bug. When I resize the window from above 600px wide to smaller, the media query takes effect and the layout changes as expected.

However, when I then increase the width to above 600px, the `<nav class="secondary_navigation">` falls below the original position - appearing below the header. Sometimes the `<a href="#" class="cta">` does the same, but not consistently.

This has been tested on Chrome only.

```
<header>
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <nav class="product_categories">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Product One</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Product Two</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <a href="#" class="cta">Call To Action</a>
    <nav class="secondary_navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Page One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

The (fairly lengthy) scss:

```
// MEDIA QUERIES
   $mq-600 : 'screen and (max-width: 600px)';

// DIMENSIONS
   $head-height : 50px;

// COLOURS
   $cta : #bada55;

header{
    background-color: rgba(0,255,255,0.75);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    ul{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li{
        display: inline-block;
        height: $head-height;
        line-height: $head-height;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        a{
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    }
    .product_categories{
        background-color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        @media #{$mq-600} {
            display: block;
            height: auto;
            li{
                background-color: #d3e1e5;
                float: left;
                height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                width: 50%;
                a{
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    span{
                        position: absolute;
                        bottom: 0;
                    }
                }
                &:before{
                    content:'';
                    display: block;
                    padding-top: 100%;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .cta{
        border: 0;
        background-color: $cta;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        @media #{$mq-600} {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
    }
    .secondary_navigation{
        background-color: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        float: right;
        @media #{$mq-600} {
            display: block;
            float: none;
        }
    }
}

h1{
    display: inline-block;
    height: $head-height;
    line-height: $head-height;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

So how can I make the second nav snap back to where it's supposed to?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/verism/fw009x2z/).

**Images as requested**:

This is correct:

[image]

But when I shrink the page and re-expand, this happens:

[image]

Comment: just tested in Chrome and FF bot latest versions and got different results. I'm not quiet sure  how supposed to end up the final result either desktop or mobile display. can you provide some images on how you want?

Comment: after OP updated question: Working 100% in FF

Comment: @dippas: but not in Chrome, I assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw009x2z/3/

I have done a small change in yours:
changed

```
display: block;
```

to

```
width: 100%;
```

for some reason, switching it to and from `block` is not appreciated by some browsers.

Comment: Superb - very much appreciated.